# Changing the definition of a workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation

We have a WF 4.5 workflow created using the VS designer and stored in a .xaml file that we want to alter programmatically before it is invoked. We only want to swap one activity out for another depending on the results of a service call.  When I try to do a proof of concept, I cannot get the updated definition to run.

```
        ChangeMe changeMe = new ChangeMe();
        DynamicUpdateServices.PrepareForUpdate(changeMe);
        var sequence = WorkflowInspectionServices.GetActivities(changeMe).ToArray()[0] as Sequence;
        sequence.Activities.RemoveAt(0);
        WriteLine writeLine = new WriteLine();
        writeLine.Text = new InArgument<string>("after");
        sequence.Activities.Insert(0, writeLine);
        WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(changeMe);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

The `ChangeMe` activity is an activity that has a single `Sequence` that contains a single `WriteLine` activity that prints "before".  I want to be able to swap out that write line activity for a new one that says after.  It is important to swap it out and not just change the text because in the future we want to be able to use an `Activity` of a different type.

This code compiles and runs, but instead of displaying "after" it displays "before".

Is it possible to do what I am asking?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The trick was create an `ActivityBuilder` using `XamlServices` which could then easily be modified:

```
        string xaml = File.ReadAllText("../../ChangeMe.xaml");
        ActivityBuilder ab = XamlServices.Load(ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderReader(
            new XamlXmlReader(new StringReader(xaml))
            )) as ActivityBuilder;
        Sequence root = ab.Implementation as Sequence;
        WriteLine writeLine = new WriteLine();
        writeLine.Text = new InArgument<string>("after");
        root.Activities[0] = writeLine;
        WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(ab.Implementation);
        Console.ReadKey();
```